# How can I print the elements of 3 different String Arrays in a certain order?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have 3 different arrays one with words of 6 letters other array with words of 5 letters and other with words of 4 letters. I need at most one word of each length per line. First, the word of longest length (6) appears if there is such a word that hasn’t already been placed in the line. Then a space, then a word of the medium length (5) if available. Then, finally a word of the shortest length (4) if available. making use of \n and \t
example:

```
Array1:[banana, orange, null, null, null, null, null]
Array2:[apple, orang, range, green, ocean, null, null, null, null]
Array3:[taco, oran, rang, blue, pool, done, null, null, null, null, null]
```

output:

```
banana apple taco
        orange orang oran
                range rang
                        green blue
                                ocean pool
                                        done
```

this is what i have tried but it only prints the first line correctly.

```
  public static String output(String[] fourLetter, String[] fiveLetter, String[] sixLetter){


            String answer = null;
            String answer1 = null;
            String answer2 = null;
            String answer3 = null;


            for (int i =0 ; i < sixLetter.length;i++){
            answer1 = sixLetter[i] +" ";


            for (int j =0 ; j <  fiveLetter.length;j++){
                answer2 = answer1+ fiveLetter[j] +" ";

                for (int k =0 ; k <  fourLetter.length;k++){

                    for(int l = 0;l<3;l++){

                            answer3 += answer2 +shortest[k]+"\n\t";

                    }
                }
            }
        }answer = answer3;

        return answer;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have so many for-loops. Have a look at this:

```
public static String output(String[] fourLetter, String[] fiveLetter, String[] sixLetter){


    String answer = "";
    for(int i=0; i<Math.max(Math.max(fourLetter.length, fiveLetter.length),sixLetter.length);i++){

        if(sixLetter.length>i){
            answer += sixLetter[i] + " ";
        }
        if(fiveLetter.length>i){
            answer += fiveLetter[i] + " ";
        }
        if(fourLetter.length>i){
            answer += fourLetter[i];
        }
        answer += "\n";
    }
    return answer;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified the Markus's code to provide the output the way you mentioned.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> abc= Arrays.asList(8,3,5,4,4,4,4,4,3,2,7,11,12,7,7,7,7,1,2);

    String[] fourL={"taco", "oran", "rang", "blue", "pool", "done"};
    String[] fiveL={"apple", "orang", "range", "green", "ocean"};
    String[] sixL={"banana", "orange"};

    System.out.println(Algo.output(fourL, fiveL, sixL));

}
public static String output(String[] fourLetter, String[] fiveLetter, String[] sixLetter){


    String answer = "";
    int count=1;
    for(int i=0; i<Math.max(Math.max(fourLetter.length, fiveLetter.length),sixLetter.length);i++){

        if(sixLetter.length>i){
            answer += sixLetter[i] + " ";
        }
        if(fiveLetter.length>i){
            answer += fiveLetter[i] + " ";
        }
        if(fourLetter.length>i){
            answer += fourLetter[i];
        }
        answer += "\n";

        for(int j=0; j<count;j++){
             answer += "\t";
        }
        count++;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

See the above code with main method.

Comment: I have tried this and it only prints the first and second line nothing else

Comment: added the main method call to this method.....try this...it works. Class name is 'Algo'